# The request is not determined by the text

Tags: sql, ruby, shoes

Where is the mistake?

If a request for hard-coded 'test' instead @edit.text then a success, but if using a variable then the request fails.

```
require 'sqlite3'

Shoes.app do

  db = SQLite3::Database.new("test.db")
  db.execute("create table t1 ( one VARCHAR(30), two INTEGER )")
  db.execute("insert into t1 ( one, two ) values ('test', 55)")

  @edit = edit_line

  button 'Search' do
    db.execute("select * from t1 where one = ?", @edit.text) do |rows|
      @test_out.text = rows
    end
  end

  @test_out = para ''

end
```

PS After some experimentation, I decided that question this way:

```
button 'Search' do
  text = @edit.text.force_encoding("UTF-8")
  db.execute("select * from t1 where one = ?", text) do |rows|
  @test_out.text = rows
  end
end
```

but my file encoding UTF-8

or as follows:

```
button 'Search' do
  text = ''
  @edit.text.each_char { |ch| text << ch }
  db.execute("select * from t1 where one = ?", text) do |rows|
  @test_out.text = rows
  end
end
```

why this strange behavior?

Comment: in this example if you type in edit_line 'test' we have to get the output 'test55' but unfortunately nothing is displayed. Why?

Comment: is there any errors when you press `alt+/`?

Comment: No, none. I do not know where to dig.

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
db.execute("select * from t1 where one = ?", "#{@edit.text}") do |rows|
  @test_out.text = rows
end
```

but it's really, really odd. I'll try to figure it out.